# I deleted my Apple ID Calendar on iCloud, how do I get it back?

Tags: data-synchronization, calendar, apple-id, network

On my iPad, I accidentally deleted my calendar named with my apple id, thinking i didnt need it. Now, it wont allow me to sync my phone or the iPad with Cloud Calendar... it doesnt even appear as an option in the iTunes sync on my PC.. only Outlook is a sync option. How can I restore that apparently important calendar so I can sync between all my devices again??

Thanks!
Christie

Comment: Are you sure you deleted the calendar app? I don't think you can delete the included Apple apps. You might have deleted your iCloud account login information and that's easy to set up again in settings. Or, as your title says, did you delete the calendar information on iCloud with your browser on your computer? I'm not sure how you can do that globally (for all information).

Answer (score 1):

You can log into [iCloud.com](http://icloud.com) from any computer and recreate calendars. Once that empty calendar populates to your devices, you can re-enter any appointments by hand or load a backup file containing the events as works for you.